# How to update an xlsx file which is saved in AWS S3 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write a xlsx file in AWS S3 using Python, Pandas and XlsxWriter:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(settings.S3_BUCKET_URL + excel_file_url,
                            engine='xlsxwriter',
                            options={'constant_memory': True})

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'https://xxxxx/1f6b1eb2-b32b-11e7-98ec-4485005d8734.xlsx'
```

Anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to avoid it.

Comment: Please format your post properly, this is unreadable

Comment: Do you get the same error with `'constant_memory': False`? Also, you can't update a file with XlsxWriter.